# Is it secure to use apache mod_mono with more virtualhosts?

Tags: apache-2.2, security, nginx, mono

I am using apache2 with mod_php and mpm_itk_module to run every virtualhost under its user. Now I am looking at mono (mod_mono) and I am not sure, if it is secure to run mono as only one process, whom the request is given by apache. The same I see with nginx & fastcgi mono. Are these really secure ways to run ASP.NET mono application on linux server?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's secure to do this but all AppDomain's will be subject to the same configuration. If you need to define different quotas, isolate experimental code or use a different version of mono you will need to run multiple instances of mod-mono-server.

See the [documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono) for more information